# chmod settings wont set

Tags: macos, osx-lion, chmod

I am trying to `chmod` a folder in `OS X Lion`

However the settings do not seem to stay when I do...

```
users-MacBook-Air:MAMP user$ sudo chmod a=rwx /tmp

users-MacBook-Air:MAMP user$ ls -l /tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Jul 20 23:44 /tmp -> private/tmp
```

Comment: this is a question better asked on [su] (and you might even get more useful answers, too!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first letter `l` in `lrwxr-xr-x` means that `/tmp` is a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

This part `/tmp -> private/tmp` means that it links to `private/tmp`.

From `man chmod`:

> **chmod** never changes the permissions of symbolic  links;  the  **chmod**
>          system call cannot change their permissions.  This is not a problem
>          since the permissions of symbolic links are never  used.   However,
>          for  each  symbolic  link listed on the command line, **chmod** changes
>          the permissions of the pointed-to file.  In contrast, **chmod** ignores
>          symbolic links encountered during recursive directory traversals.

So, you can safely ignore your link's permissions.

Note that `private/tmp` is a path relative to the folder where `/tmp` is located - `/`. Its absolute path is `/private/tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to set permissions on a symbolic link. That is not possible. Instead, apply the chmod to *private/tmp*

Comment: That gives me a `no such file or directory error` This is not a symbolic link to the best of my knowledge. it is in `Applications/MAMP/tmp`

Comment: It is a symbolic link. Try `chmod a=rwx /Applications/MAMP/private/tmp`

Answer (score 1):

Tested on macOS.

You can change the permissions of the symbolic link by writing `chmod -h 755 file`. From the `chmod` manual, the `-h` option changes the mode of the symbolic link instead of the file the link points to. Without the `-h` option, `chmod` would just change the file mode of the file that the symbolic link points to.

Keep in mind to check whether or not the file permission was successfully set or not because there are some cases where despite issuing the correct command, the symbolic link will not be set. I do not know the exact process causing the following, but it appears there are certain security settings which cause the permission of the symbolic link to be modifiable only under certain users.

If you are not the root user, you could temporarily modify the permissions of the symbolic link by operating on it in the `/tmp` folder. The `/tmp` folder is a special folder because its sticky bit is set. Read `man sticky`* to learn more about sticky bits, it even lists `/tmp` as an example folder. Any directory owned by root whose sticky bit is set would work, but `/tmp` is the directory most likely to be available on a given machine. This matters because as a directory owned by root whose sticky bit is set, it allows non-root users to write to files owned by root. This means that if you find that when you attempt to modify the permissions of a symbolic link it keeps reverting to its old permission, you can attempt to modify the permissions of the symbolic link within `/tmp` and it will retain its newly set permissions. However, keep in mind that if you had faced the obstacle of the reverting permissions in the first place, then moving the file back to its original directory would cause the permissions to revert to whatever it always reverts to. In my case it reverted to absolute mode `0777`. Also, keep in mind that the permissions of symbolic link do not affect the permissions that you have in accessing the file it links to, since those are determined by the permissions of that file itself.

*In the terminal, type `man sticky` and hit `ENTER`, and documentation for `sticky` will be displayed. Press `q` to exit. Alternatively, see [Sticky bit on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit).